# Rails MVC - Proper Way to Access User Session Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, model-view-controller, coding-style

What is the "best practices" approach to this Rails problem?

Registration controller & model "registers" new users
Sessions controller & model "logs in" users
Both access a 3rd party API for the actual User model / registration / login

If a new user meets certain criteria, after they are registered, we want to automatically log them in.

```
@registration = Registrations.new(registrations_params)  
if @registration.create  
  # log in the user  
end
```

Is it good practice to log in the user by calling the session object from the registrations controller?
`@session.create`
If not, what is the acceptable standard for accomplishing sessions creation upon new user registration?

Comment: This should be interesting. In my app, when a new user is created (via a signup form) this is exactly what I did to log them in after signing up. So inside my users controller, in my User.create,once the user is created -  I pass the log_in method (from my sessions helper) and it works like a charm.